# I want to make a 'Spoiler Alert' button

Tags: javascript, html, button, background-color

I want to make a 'Spoiler Alert' button.

First of all, I don't know anything.
I'm really sorry.

I'm doing this because I suddenly want to do it.

Anyway, this is my best result.

```html
<button id="change9">Spoiler Alert</button>

<script>

document.getElementById("change9").onclick = function(){
    document.body.style.color = '#ffffff';
}

</script>




<p>&nbsp;</p>

Not Spoiler 

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<span style="background-color:#000000;">Spoiler</span><br />
```

But what I really wanted was to have both results. (Not Spoiler/Spoiler)

In other words,
... span style="background-color:#000000;" ...
I want to delete this part by clicking a button.

Is it possible?

I've been looking for it,
But there is only a way to change the entire background color,
and I can't find a way to change the text background color.

Comment: _First of all, I don't know anything._ Well said. This statement is the foundation for all knowledge in the universe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a fleshed out version of code that handles multiple spoiler alert buttons for each spoiler

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".showspoiler").forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.querySelector(`.${this.dataset.target}`).classList.toggle('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.spoiler {
  color: #ffffff00;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.spoiler.show {
  color: #ffffffff;
}
```

```html
<button class="showspoiler" data-target="spoiler1">Spoiler Alert</button>
<br/> Not Spoiler
<br/>
<span class="spoiler spoiler1">Spoiler</span><br />
<br/>
<button class="showspoiler" data-target="spoiler2">Spoiler Alert</button>
<br/> Another Not Spoiler
<br/>
<span class="spoiler spoiler2">Another Spoiler</span><br />
```

Though - the way I'd do it is different, I wouldn't have buttons, I'd just click on the spoiler itself

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".spoiler").forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    this.classList.toggle('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.spoiler {
  color: #ffffff00;
  background-color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.spoiler.show {
  color: #ffffffff;
}
```

```html
Not Spoiler
<br/>
<span class="spoiler spoiler1">Spoiler</span><br />
<br/>
Another Not Spoiler
<br/>
<span class="spoiler spoiler2">Another Spoiler</span><br />
```

Answer (score 2):

When you click the button, you have to tell the javascript which element to change. We could tell it to change a `span` tag but you might have more than one. So I put a `class` on it called "spoiler". And you can then do something like this:

```
document.querySelector('.spoiler').style.color="#ffffff";
```

However, it's better (and easier) to work with css and classes. So instead, I set up a class called 'clicked' and now we just add that to the span like this:

```
document.querySelector('.spoiler').classList.add('clicked');
```

```js
document.getElementById("change9").onclick = function(e) {
  document.querySelector('.spoiler').classList.add('clicked');
}
```

```css
.spoiler {
  background: #000;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

.spoiler.clicked {
  background: #fff;
  color: #f00;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<button id="change9">Spoiler Alert</button>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
Not Spoiler
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<span class='spoiler'>Spoiler</span><br />
```

Comment: It is better to hide the spoiler using `visibility: hidden` instead of making the text color equal to the background. (Unless you want the user to be able to reveal it by selecting the hidden text.)

Comment: @jfd348 - with visibility:hidden you can't see where the spoiler is

Comment: @Jaromanda X If you want the background to remain visible, you can use a span nested in another, set the background color to the outer span and the visibility to the inner one.

Comment: @jfd348 - thanks. I completely missed the whole point. Fixed

Comment: @jfd348 - if your comment mentioned that, I wouldn't have said a thing :p

Answer (score 1):

You are close! Give an ID to the SPAN:

```
<span id="myspoiler" style="background-color:#000000;">Spoiler</span>
```

Then change body to your new ID

```
document.getElementById("myspoiler").style.color = '#ffffff';
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is my snippet:

```html
<button id="change">Spoiler Alert</button>
<br><br>

<span>Not Spoiler</span>
<br><br>

<span class='spoiler' id='spoiled'>Spoiler</span>
```

```css
.spoiler {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  color: red;
}
```

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("change");
let spoilSpan = document.getElementById("spoiled");
btn.addEventListener("click", spoilerAlert);

function spoilerAlert() {
  spoilSpan.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you guys, I got what I wanted.
Thank you.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".spoiler").forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    this.classList.toggle('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.spoiler {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.spoiler.show {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
Not Spoiler
<br/>
<span class="spoiler spoiler1">Spoiler</span><br />
<br/>
Another Not Spoiler
<br/>
<span class="spoiler spoiler2">Another Spoiler</span><br />
```