# I want to make a 'Spoiler Alert' button (2)

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

[I want to make a 'Spoiler Alert' button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68028767)

First of all, thanks to you guys, I got what I wanted.
But, One more question came to my mind.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("change");
let spoilSpan = document.getElementById("spoiled");
btn.addEventListener("click", spoilerAlert);

function spoilerAlert() {
  spoilSpan.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.spoiler {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  padding: 1px;
}

.show {
  display: inline-block;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="change">Spoiler Alert</button>
<br><br>

<span>Not Spoiler</span>
<br><br>

<span class='spoiler' id='spoiled'>
  Spoiler
</span><br><br>
  
<span>Not Spoiler</span>
<br><br>

<span class='spoiler' id='spoiled'>
  Spoiler
</span>
```

I want it to work with one button.
However, the last "Spoiler" doesn't work.

What should I do?

I'm sorry for not knowing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having multiple elements with the same `id` makes your HTML invalid. In that case, `getElementById` will return only the first matching element which is not what you need.

Write this instead:

```
function spoilerAlert() {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('spoiler')).forEach(x => {
    x.classList.toggle("show");
  });
}
```

Your snippet fixed below:

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("change");
let spoilSpan = document.getElementById("spoiled");
btn.addEventListener("click", spoilerAlert);

function spoilerAlert() {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('spoiler')).forEach(x => {
    x.classList.toggle("show");
  });
}
```

```css
.spoiler {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  padding: 1px;
}

.show {
  display: inline-block;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="change">Spoiler Alert</button>
<br><br>

<span>Not Spoiler</span>
<br><br>

<span class='spoiler' id='spoiled'>
  Spoiler
</span><br><br>
  
<span>Not Spoiler</span>
<br><br>

<span class='spoiler' id='spoiled'>
  Spoiler
</span>
```